payments import from python_flutterwave not working.... python 3.12.4
This is the inport i have in my code
    from python_flutterwave import payment

But i am getting an error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'payment' from 'python_flutterwave' (C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\STechnologies-Suite\STech-Agent-Suite\env\Lib\site-packages\python_flutterwave_init_.py).
How is this possible yet according to the docs, it should be working just fine.

I noticed that the python-flutterwave actually didn't have any payments attribute in any of its files. I created a payments.py file and included code that would give it what to do on payments. After that, I can now successfully run the code.
